How do I configure the Google Picker API to not show files which have a particular custom property?
We are trying to integrate the Google Picker with an external system, and as part of the integration we want to prevent users from seeing documents which have come from the external system - the way that this is done elsewhere is by filtering based on a custom property, e.g.  "EXTERNAL_SYSTEM_URI" which is embedded into any documents which have come from the system.
This property is available in the Google File.Properties parameter.
Is there a way to configure the Google Picker to not show documents which have a particular property?
I have found how to filter based on file type, something similar to this would be ideal.
